# JSF ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, icefaces

I asked about this problem, but I didn't get any help.
Let say I have this portion of code in my `xhtml`

```
<h:form id="viewSnForm" prependId="false">   

                <h:commandButton  id="kopce" value="kopce">
                    <f:ajax event="click" render="panelTarget" execute="kopce" listener="#{myBean.loop()}"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:panelGroup id="panelTarget">
                    <h:outputText id="target" value="#{myBean.num}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

            </h:form>
```

and my backing bean `myBean.java` looks something like this

```
public void runMyScript(){
    JavaScriptRunner.runScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
            "console.log('my_check'); document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = " + this.num + ";");
}

public void loop(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.num += 1;

        runMyScript();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyCompanyBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

in my bean I am counting to 10 and I like to simulate that whit 2 sec of waiting among each instrumentation, but in my `xhtml` I don't see the response immediately, only when the method finishes. In my browser's console I can see all `my_check` logs but only when there are 20sec passed.
What I want is to display `num` after every 2 sec, i.e. every increment in the `loop()` method.

This code is only improvisation. What I really want to do is attach percentages to my loading spinner.

I tried different solutions, but none could work for me. Please share your opinions and experience with me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. Since in normal method calls, the server only sends data back to the client when the method finishes. Two possible solutions:

- Use client-side polling
- Use server Push

And with some very simple google usage, I found [this icefaces component](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=progressBarBean_) Which supports both (and I'm not even an IceFaces user)